# How to get array in http request

Tags: go

For this request `GET http://localhost:8080/path?my_key%5B%5D=3&my_key%5B%5D=4&my_key%5B%5D=5`

I can't get the data from `my_key`. I tried `req.URL.Query()["my_key"]`. I can get it if I change the request encoding to from `my_key%5B%5D=4&my_key%5B%5D=5` to `my_key=4&my_key=5`

How can I get request URL's in form of `my_key[]=value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [net/url](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/) package

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    utmp := "http://localhost:8080/path?my_key%5B%5D=3&my_key%5B%5D=4&my_key%5B%5D=5"
    u, err := url.Parse(utmp)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(u.Query()["my_key[]"])
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/t2O7KnUbZOA

Your key is `"my_key[]"` not `"my_key"`

Comment: the live code example provided currently does not work